# Display the image's filename without extension as a title

Tags: php, html, image, title

first of all, I am a noob in PHP. I am trying to achieve something like this.

I have a photo named "Test Image.jpg". Then, the image tag inside some other php functions. Is there a way that I could show the filename without the extensions (in this case Test Image), as the title of that image?

Here is my code:

```
<? foreach($dy_matmirat as $key => $image) : ?>
    <td valign="top"><img src="images/<?=$image->filename?>" width="70" /></td>
<td valign="top">Mesatarja: <?=$image->wins-$image->losses?></td>
    <? endforeach ?>
```

I hope that somebody can help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function.

```
<?=basename($image->filename, '.jpg')?>
```

This will strip the extension from your filename.

Edit: forgot the second parameter.

This solution works if you know by advance the extension you want to remove.

You can also use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$fileparts = pathinfo("Test Image.jpg");
echo $fileparts['filename']; // prints Test Image
```

Comment: This worked, but it's showing the full file name, with the extensions also. Can you please confirm if you posted the right code?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now. You just forgot to add a "." before jpg, so the full working code would be:

`<?=basename($image->filename, '.jpg')?>`

Comment: yes indeed ! it's late round here, I should probably go to bed :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = $image->filename;
$name = substr($name,0,strripos($name,"."));

echo $name;
```

Comment: This isn't working, I don't know why. Maybe I don't know how to correctly use it.